# R: State and County Outlines for choroplethrZip

Tags: r, zipcode, choropleth

I have a dataset with zip codes that I have used choroplethrZip to graph the data. I am looking at the data on the state and county level.  However, zip codes don't necessarily correspond with state and county lines. I have tried to use reference_map = TRUE, but it doesn't have county lines, and starts to look a little busy.  Is there a way to change the default reference map to one that has state and county lines without the rest of the map detail? In other words, I don't want streets and topography.

Here is my code with the sample data that is similar to the data I am using.  You can see the issue with the state of Texas boundaries.

```
#zip.regions metadata file for choroplethrZip
data(zip.regions)
head(zip.regions)

#Test data file:A data.frame containing population estimates 
# for US Zip Code Tabulated Areas (ZCTAs) in 2012.
data(df_pop_zip) 

#Create a choropleth of US Zip Codes
zip_choropleth(df_pop_zip, 
               state_zoom="texas", 
               title="2012 Texas State ZCTA Population Estimates",
               legend="Population",
               reference_map = TRUE)

#Zoom County
dd_fips = c(48113, 48121)
zip_choropleth(df_pop_zip, 
               county_zoom=dd_fips,  
               title="2012 Denton & Dallas ZCTA Population Estimates",
               legend="Population",
               reference_map = TRUE)
```

[TexasPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTgAP.png)

[DentonDallasPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc05B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this blog and found out how to make this work: http://www.arilamstein.com/blog/2015/07/02/exploring-the-demographics-of-ferguson-missouri/

Here is my final code:

```
library(choroplethrZip)
library(ggplot2)
library(choroplethr)


#Pull in zip.regions metadata file for choroplethrZip
data(zip.regions)
head(zip.regions)

#Test data file:A data.frame containing population estimates 
# for US Zip Code Tabulated Areas (ZCTAs) in 2012.
data(df_pop_zip)

# highlight a county
highlight_county = function(county_fips)
{
  library(choroplethrMaps)
  data(county.map, package="choroplethrMaps", envir=environment())
  df = county.map[county.map$region %in% county_fips, ]
  geom_polygon(data=df, aes(long, lat, group = group), color = "yellow", fill = NA, size = 1)
}

#Zoom County
dd_fips = c(48113, 48121)
zip_choropleth(df_pop_zip, 
               county_zoom=dd_fips,  
               title="2012 Denton & Dallas ZCTA Population Estimates",
               legend="Population",
               reference_map = TRUE) +
              highlight_county(dd_fips)
```

[Rplot Counties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWNLX.png)

I just had to add in the highlight_county function and it worked great. When I tested with my data (instead of the generic population data) it worked as well.